# Why is $\sin^{-1}0$ equal to $0$ and not $2\pi$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse-function

The definition of inverse function is that the function must be one to one. However, as the sine function isn't one to one, how is $\sin^{-1}$, the inverse of the sine function?

Is it due to the periodic property of trigonometric curves? $\iff \sin(0)=0$ and $\sin(2\pi)=0$ (in radians).

If I throw the output into the inverse function I get $0$. Why not $2\pi$?

Comment: $\sin^{-1}( x)$ only assumes values in $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right]$, where $\sin x$ is indeed one-one.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: $arcsin = sin{-1}$ is not an inverse of sine function. $arcsin$ is an inverse of the sine restricted to $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin x$ takes a value $y$ at many $x$. If we define an inverse [relation](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(mathematics)), that relation can take many values $x$ at its input $y$. In order for that relation to be a *[function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) by definition*, it has to take only one value of $x$ at its input $y$. Hence we define $\sin^{-1}y=x$, where $y\in\left[-1,1\right]$ is what sine could map to only, such that $x$ belongs to $\left[-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2\right]$ only. Outside these boundaries for $x$, inverse sine is not a function but a mere relation.

Comment: Thanks, that was an awesome explanation.

Comment: As a little addition: there are (infinitely) many inverses of sin (which essentially mean range restrictions of the inverse relation, resulting in a function), and that one is only a choice made by convention.